# JavaFX How to get a children (WebView) from a Tab?

Tags: java, javafx

I have just started to do things with JavaFX and I'm trying to 'build' an browser. Right now I have a TabPane with two tabs. One tab has a WebView and the other tab is able to add new tabs. Over the TabPane is a Textfield. When I enter an internet adress I want to load a website in the selected Tab.

My Problem  is, that I dont know how to get the Webview inside the selected Tab. I was able to get the selected Tab, but I have no Idea how to get the WebView inside it.

```
int index = TabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
Tab selectedTab = TabPane.getTabs().get(index);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always call `selectedTab.getContent()`, and then navigate down through the scene graph hierarchy until you get to the right element. E.g. if your tab content is a `BorderPane` and the `WebView` is in the center you could do

```
BorderPane selectedBorderPane = (BorderPane) selectedTab.getContent();
WebView selectedWebView = (WebView) selectedBorderPane.getCenter();
```

This is pretty ugly code, though, and you'd have to rewrite it any time you changed the layout, which means your application becomes hard to maintain.

A (much) better way would be to create a variable at the appropriate scope (controller for the view that displays the tab pane, or the class that contains it if you're doing the layout in Java) for the current web view:

```
private WebView currentWebView ;
```

Then whenever you create a new tab containing a web view, add a listener to the tab's `selectedProperty`:

```
Tab tab = new Tab(...);
// ...
WebView webView = new WebView(...);
// ... layout, etc tab content, etc...
tab.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
    if (isNowSelected) {
        currentWebView = webView ;
    }
});
```

Now `currentWebView` always references the currently displayed web view. (You will also need to initialize it to the first web view displayed at startup.)